# Java SSL server socket does not respond to encrypted handshake message

Tags: java, ssl, handshake

I have one Java application which creates a SSL server socket and transfers data to the clients.  Both the server and the client supports SSL renegotiation. The client starts SSL renegotiation 300s after it connects to the server.

From the wireshark traces, the client have sent a encrypted handshake message to the server port sucessfully during the data transfer, but the server did not give reply to this handshake message. I have tried Java SSL debug (-Djavax.net.debug=all ), and this handshake message is even not visible in the debug prints, while the handshake messages in the SSL connecton establishment are there and also the application data are printed. The result is that the data transfer continues and is sucessfully complete without any exception but the encrypted handshake message is ignored.

My question are:

1, is there any case that a encrypted handshake message won't be printed via the mentioned SSL debug?

2, is there any case that Java will ignore the handshake message without response like the handshake  message has incorrect content?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure renegotiation is set to off by default.  You can turn it back on though, explanation here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/tlsreadme-141115.html

Comment: Thanks for the info. However, even with the system property "-Dsun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation=true", the renegotiation handshake message from the client still can't be detected by SSL server socket. Actually the handshake message is even not printed in the SSL debug traces. it seems that this handshake message is not received by Java SSL server socket at all. This  happens on both Java 7 and Java 8.  I am thinking if this handshake message is blocked by OS so not sent to the application.